# Script to remove submesh in all objects by material name?

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I wonder if it would be possible to write a python script that could remove all vertices across all objects that are part of the same material. There are 250+ objects and I need to remove all mesh data from the body, leaving just the armour. I would then need to unlink this material from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will loop through the selected objects and through their  verts/edges/faces to remove the ones assigned to a specific material and delete them :

- select all the objects
- select the material (in material slots )
- run the script

---

```
import bpy
import bmesh


mat_name = bpy.context.object.active_material.name

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects :
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    mat_id = bpy.context.object.material_slots.find(mat_name)

    for v in bm.verts:
        delete = True
        for f in v.link_faces :
            if f.material_index != mat_id :
                delete = False
        if delete :
            bm.verts.remove(v)

    for e in bm.edges:
        delete = True
        for f in e.link_faces :
            if f.material_index != mat_id :
                delete = False
        if delete :
            bm.edges.remove(e)

    for f in bm.faces:
        if f.material_index == mat_id :
            bm.faces.remove(f)

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I just created a whole new race for the game I'm working on!